# checking a nested list using input separated by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

so I am trying to make minesweeper using a nested list, and I need to use input separated by a comma, to check if there is a bomb per se at "3,4"

My function for this takes in a nested list and is supposed to take in two integers representing a row and column.

What I am doing though is this :

```
def isMineAt(gameBoard, guess1, guess2) :
    guess = input(("Enter a number for the row, then a number for the column"))
    mainList = []
    for i in range (0, int(guess)) :
        mainList = guess.split(',')
    print(mainList)
```

and then in main() I have :

```
isMineAt(gameBoard, '', '')
```

What I'm getting is an error that says : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,4'

Could anyone shed some light as to what is going on? and

Comment: `int(guess)` is trying to do `int('3,4')` which is of course not possible. There are more errors like this in your code. You need to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/). I'm serious.

Comment: @timgeb I know my code is buggy for example with my empty strings as arguments, however the prof says to take integers as arguments but the logical way to me is get the integers from the user once in the function, maybe I need to just take a break from my code and look at it in a bit

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
def isMineAt(gameboard, guess1, guess2) :
    guess = str(input(("Enter a number for the row, then a number for the column")))
    mainList = list(map(int,guess.split(',')))
    print(mainList)
isMineAt(gameboard, '', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

The program needs to handle user input properly, and probably with some better error checking.

The user is entering some string "3,2" but maybe also "3 2" or "bananas!".

So first for the easy case:

```
try:
    row,col = guess.split(",")
    row = int(row)
    col = int(col)
except:
    print("Give input as integers: row,column")
```

The parameters `guess1` and `guess2` are not used.

So this whole script, should probably be broken into two functions:

```
### Prompt the user for some input, where they should enter
### Two comma separated integers.
### Return the inputted numbers to ints, returning row, col.
def getUserGuess():
    row, col = (-1, -1)
    while row == -1:
        user_input = input("Give row & column numbers> ")
        try:
            row,col = guess.split(",")
            row = int(row)
            col = int(col)         
        except:
            print("Error in input: expected Number,Number")
            row = -1   # go around the loop again

     return row, col

### Return True if the board has a mine at (row, col)
def isMineAt(board, row, col):
    # TODO - verify row & col are within the bounds of the board
    return board[row][col] == True  # probably not a useful function
```